# Keras model compiles well outside SageMaker. But as soon as i try to train it in SageMaker with the Tensorflow instance i get an error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

Here is the error: **ValueError:** **Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata)**

I try to train and deploy a **multi-input** Keras model with AWS Sagemaker, but there seem to be some showstopper issues with the needed libraries that expect single input for Keras models.

I have **3 categorical inputs** variables and **one numeric variable**. The **target variable is also of type categorical**.I have no test or validation data. I am only interested in the training without errors.

I **merged** the arrays after data preparation as follows and then **stored them in s3**

```
input_train = np.column_stack((input_cat1, input_cat2, input_num, input_cat3))
training_input_path = sage_maker_session.upload_data('data/training.npz', key_prefix=prefix + training_folder)
print(training_input_path)
s3://sagemaker-eu-central-1-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/user_tracking/training/training.npz
```

In the **train.py script (entry_point)**, I again fetched the file from s3. And I compiled the Train.py file again without problems, as if I were outside SageMaker.

```
%%writefile train.py
### import library ###

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=60)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    #parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING'])
    #parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default='data')
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
    epochs     = args.epochs
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    model_dir  = args.model_dir
    training_dir   = args.training

    input_train =np.load(os.path.join(training_dir, 'training.npz'))['train_input']
    target =np.load(os.path.join(training_dir, 'training.npz'))['train_output']

    input_cat1 = input_train[:,0].astype(np.int32)
    input_cat2 = input_train[:,1].astype(np.int32)
    input_cat3 = input_train[:,3:].astype(np.int32)
    input_num = input_train[:,2].astype(np.float32)

    n_steps = 2                        # number of timesteps in each sample
    num_unique_os = 5                  #len(le_betriebsystem.classes_)+1
    num_unique_browser = 10            #len(le_browser.classes_)+1
    num_unique_actions = 210           #len(le_actionen.classes_)+1

    #numeric Input 
    numerical_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='numeric_input')
    #categorical Input
    os_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='os_input')
    browser_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='browser_input')
    action_input= tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_seq_len,), name='action_input')

    emb_os = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_unique_os, 32)(os_input) 
    emb_browser = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_unique_browser, 32)(browser_input)
    emb_actions = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_unique_actions, 64)(action_input)
    actions_repr = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(300, return_sequences=True)(emb_actions)
    actions_repr = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(200)(emb_actions)
    emb_os = tf.squeeze(emb_os, axis=1)
    emb_browser = tf.squeeze(emb_browser, axis=1)
    activity_repr = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([emb_os, emb_browser, actions_repr, 
    numerical_input])
    x = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(n_steps)(activity_repr)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(288, return_sequences=True)(x) 
    next_n_actions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_unique_actions-1, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[numerical_input, os_input, browser_input, action_input], outputs = 
    next_n_actions)
    model.summary()
    model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit({'numeric_input': input_num,
        'os_input': input_cat1,
        'browser_input': input_cat2,
        'action_input': input_cat3}, target, batch_size=50, epochs=130) 
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    tf.keras.backend.get_session(),
    os.path.join(model_dir, '1'),
    inputs={'inputs': model.input},
    outputs={t.name: t for t in model.outputs})
```

I received this:
[Model Sommary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvs4S.png)
[Meric Tendency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msq1L.png)

when trying to do the whole thing again with the Tensorflow instance, the following error occurred:
**Traceback (most recent call last): File "train.py", line 105, in model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[numerical_input, os_input, browser_input, action_input], outputs = next_n_actions)** File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 121, in init super(Model, self).init(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 80, in init self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper method(self, *args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 224, in _init_graph_network '(thus holding past layer metadata). Found: ' + str(x)) **ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow Layer (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("dense/truediv:0", shape=(?, 2, 209), dtype=float32) 2021-03-08 21:52:04,761 sagemaker-containers ERROR ExecuteUserScriptError: Command "/usr/bin/python train.py --batch-size 50 --epochs 150--model_dir s3://sagemaker-eu-central-1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode**

I used the **Tensorflow versions '2.0.4' and '1.15.4'** respectly with the kernels **conda_tensorflow_p36** and **conda_tensorflow2_p36**

For more of Code: https://gitlab.com/patricksardin08/data-science/-/tree/master/

Please i need your Helps. I'm here around the clock if anyone wants me to explain the question in more detail.

Comment: The problem is that you are doing tensorflow operations directly on Keras Tensors, that is not supported in earlier versions of Keras, for that you would need to wrap any tf operation inside a Lambda layer.

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy, Thank you very for your answer. The solution you just propose is not for the case where the model already outside SageMaker does not compile? Ich würde Dich kontaktieren können, Du bist ein Expert und ich hätte noch weitere allgemeine Fragen.